# Using a full outer join in HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb

Is a full outer join supported in HSQLDB. I have been trying to use it but it doesnot work.
I am trying to do something like this.

1. Query 1 pulls data from table A as key,value
2. Query 2 pulls data from table B as Key,value
   Now i needed an outer join where by i will club the data between the two where the keys matched and also get data where the keys didnot match.
   In case outer join is not supported in HSQLDB (we are using hsqldb and cannot change the database), what is the best approach should i use to implement this efficiently.

Thanks.

Comment: I think i can use a Left outer join and club it with a union clause to match results from table 2 where keys donot match.Not sure whether this is a good approach or not.

Answer (score 0):

FULL OUTER JOIN is supported in HSQLDB 2.0. For older versions use this

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT table1.key, table1.value, table2.value FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
UNION 
SELECT table1.key, table1.value, table2.value FROM table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table1.key = table2.key
)
```